# App should launch on it's own after hitting the home button to pull the phone out of sleep mode

Tags: iphone, cydia

We have built an Cydia app for jailbroken iPhones. Now my client wants the app to launch on it's own after the user hits the home button to pull the phone out of sleep mode. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: As an iPhone owner, I hope this isn't possible.

Answer (score 1):

This would require you to redefine the functionality of the home button, or at the very least add functionality to, which Apple does not allow. It is possible, but it will get rejected from the app store.

EDIT: Didn't notice this was for jail broken iPhones, so yes you can do this. You would need to find custom Libraries, I don't know of any of the top of my head. Alternatively you could figure out what part of the private Apple API you need to use to do this.

Please note that changing button functionality is **not** the best of ideas... Perhaps you could accomplish the same thing by running in the background and using push notifications when user interaction is required?

Comment: I most certainly agree that changing the home button functionality is rather dangerous, and I strongly discourage you to do so.

Comment: As doing so is frowned upon I'm afraid I do not. However after a very brief search, http://lifehacker.com/5775631/how-to-customize-button-and-multitouch-functionality-on-your-jailbroken-ios-device This article, specifically the activator app seems to potentially be what you may want. This way you can make your app do what it needs to without including the button modification code yourself. You could try to contact the app creators as well, hopefully they can give you some pointers.

Answer (score 0):

zmaster pulled this same function off on his Android Lock jailbroken app. It shouldn't change the function of the home button, it would still pull the phone out of sleep mode but the app would launch just as any normal password protection would.